# wolfram|Alpha return no result on the limit of an integral

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want a step by step solutions and type as following:

```
=Limit[Integrate[(e^x^2 *n)/(1 + n^2 x^2), {x, 0, 1}], n -> Infinity]
```

It returns nothing but "(no interpretations available)". The formula should yield pi/2.

May I have some ideas on how to get this right? Thank you.

Comment: I think it's just beyond its ability... It will return something without any x in the denominator...

Comment: I have updated the answer in the hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you used the character `e` to denote the Euler number. Unfortunately `e` is just a variable, and you are interested in `E`. This is the same is `pi` vs `Pi`. One is a variable the other the irrational number.

You might consider typing:

```
=Limit[Integrate[E^(x^2)*n/(1+(n*x)^2),{x,0,1}],n->Infinity]
```

or

```
=Limit[Integrate[Exp[x^2]*n/(1+(n*x)^2),{x,0,1}],n->Infinity]
```

But If you want to obtain a result using Mathematica, then you might be more interested in rewriting the integral by the substitution *n x = y*, which gives you:

```
In> Limit[Integrate[Exp[(y/n)^2]/(1+y^2),{y,0,n}],n->Infinity]
Out> Pi/2
```

This integral is very straightforward in this case as the Exponent drops to 1 and you only have to solve the standard integral:

```
In> Integrate[1/(1+y^2),{y,0,Infinity}]
Out> Pi/2
```

Another way to see this is to write the exponential function as a series expansion, leading to a sum of integrals of the form:

```
In> Limit[Integrate[y^(2 m)/(1+y^2),{y,0,n}]/(m! n^(2 m)),n->Infinity]
```

This Limit is even simpler than before as you do not need to perform any tests to check if the Integral and the Limit are interchangeable.

Assume now that

```
I[m,n] = Integrate[y^(2 m)/(1+y^2),{y,0,n}]/(m! n^(2 m))
```

Then you know that for *m > 0*, *I[m,n] ≤ J[m,n]*, with

```
J[m,n] = Integrate[y^(2 m - 2),{y,0,n}] = n^(2m - 1)/(2m - 1)/(m! n^(2 m))
```

Since *0 ≤ I[m,n] ≤ J[m,n]*, We know that *0 ≤ I[m,Infinity] ≤ J[m,Infinity] = 0*, for *m > 1*, or *I[m,Infinity] = 0*. Which leaves us with *I[0,Infinity]*:

```
Limit[Integrate[Exp[(y/n)^2]/(1+y^2),{y,0,n}],n->Infinity] =
   Integrate[1/(1+y^2),{y,0,Infinity}]
```

Although this is not really a Mathematica question and more a Mathematics Stack Exchange question, I do believe this answers your question.